# Stack Exchange site to ask how other people are doing X?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site that permits questions of the format "How are other people doing X" (where X is pretty specific)?

Or is there a way to phrase questions like this for Stack Overflow?

For instance, "How are other companies doing security for Web API?"

Comment: You said "specific". What is specific about "security for Web API"?

Comment: @CodyGray - Poor example on my part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These questions are too broad and open ended for the Stack Exchange model.

You need to choose a site more suited for discussion.

Comment: Fair enough; can you recommend such a site that offers high-quality answers?

Comment: @TrueWill - nope, sorry.

Comment: @TrueWill Reddit is probably your best bet.  Programmers discuss all sorts of things there.  ProTip: *Make your question **interesting.***

Comment: Note: *not* `/r/programming` - it's for (mainly) discussion of articles, not self-posts.